# Unwanted white space at the bottom of the page - Can't find an answer?

Tags: html, css

I am kind of new to stackoverflow, but I came here for help... I have a really stupid question: I have an unwanted white space at the bottom of the page, this has been bothering me for days and I can't seem to fix it...
The website is:
http://mateo226.byethost4.com/plans.html
Picture:
http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh576/mateo72354/Screenshotfrom2014-06-22194407_zpse274bef9.png
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a white space.  Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: I dont see any white space. But you can try to set the background image or color to html, instead of body.

Comment: Well, I can set the background image but the screen will still look big? Is it possible that it is happening only to me?

Comment: can you provide an image or something pointing to this white space..?

Comment: I was ABOUT to do that ;) Give me a sec

Comment: Edited the post, added an img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see white space in a maximized window.  If that's what you want to get rid of, you're going to need to scale your content (which might look ugly) or space it out vertically.  Either way, I think it looks fine.

If your white space issue is browser specific, try adding at the beginning of your CSS `*{padding:0;margin:0;}` and seeing if that fixes things.

And on a personal note, move away from Byet.  They sound good to someone who's learning but aren't really as good as they seem.  I've had my best luck with ServersFree.com.

EDIT: It's just your window.  If it really bothers you and you want some framing, go ahead and give your page a center column:

```
body{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope it will fix something :) And I will try out ServersFree.com :)

Comment: Ahh, none of this helped :( I guess it works for everyone else so I am happy with that :) Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you could add a header image to make the page taller.